# Install libgcrypt11 in Heroku 16

Tags: java, heroku, ubuntu-16.04, heroku-toolbelt, .so

I just deployed my java application that has dependency on native libraries in heroku server.  My local os is Windows but heroku uses Ubuntu16.04.  So i had to replace my dll's with .so files and deploy.  But i get a runtime dependency error that - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /app/libstorj-java.so: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file.
I believe i need to install libgcrypt.so.11 in my heroku app.  But i am not sure how to do this as i am very new to heorku and linux.  I tried ssh to my app using "heroku run bash" and ran the command "apt-get install libgcrypt11". I get Unable to locate package libgcrypt11.  Anybody tried this before.

Comment: "Old `libgcrypt11`" examples https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=libgcrypt11 ... ( New Debian version is libgcrypt20 ).

Comment: but how to add it to heroku application from my windows machine?

Comment: Options : Download the Ubuntu 14 package (I missed your "Ubuntu text")  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb ... Install the package. Or add a 'trusty' line to /etc/apt/sources.list ... and install libgcrypt11 ... ... whichever you can do remotely.

Comment: Confirm, option **1** : Ubuntu 16.04, `libgcrypt11`, from "trusty-updates" → `sudo gdebi Downloads/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb` → Installs OK, no dependencies were required / no dependencies were installed

Answer (score 0):

> My local os is Windows but heroku uses Ubuntu16.04

Remote commands ... "heroku run bash"

```
wget http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb 

sudo gdebi libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb
```

P.S.: My test with Ubuntu 16.04 → `libgcrypt11` installs OK, no dependencies were required / no dependencies were installed.